# Jersey endpoints fail to load if index.html is provided

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jersey

I have a Jetty Server which serves up an Angular page but also has several Jersey endpoints coded up. My Angular project is in a `resources` directory, and after building and running, the `target` looks like this:

```
WEB-INF
    classes
        index.html
        com/
    web.xml
```

My `web.xml` looks like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<display-name>Sandbox</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <!-- Adds JSON processing to map java classes to JSON text in both directions -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- Tell the Jersey framework where to search for services.  Also, JAX-RS is needed
         for the JSON serialization -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.hb.apps.server;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
    <extension>json</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

With this set up, hitting `localhost:8080/Sandbox` serves up the single page angular app, however hitting `localhost:8080/Sandbox/rest/*` tells me that my endpoint cannot be found. The Angular app was introduced after the Jersey app, and prior to the Angular app my Jersey endpoints were working fine with this configuration (minus the `welcome-file-list`). Why would having an Angular app obscure my Jersey endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was unrelated to the web.xml. One of my colleagues had assisted me with setting up the project to work with Angular and had removed this block from my pom file:

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
</resource>
```